# SPSS Chi-Square using only percentages

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, percentage

Here's the data that I have (percentages only)

Gender:

- M = 60%
- F = 40%

Expected:

- M = 50%
- F = 50%

How do I use SPSS to run $\chi^2$ test since I only have the percentages?

Comment: Don't you need group sizes in order to account for the uncertainty of these percentages? 60% females out of ten individuals is a very different estimate compared to 60% females out of a thousand individuals.

Comment: cc:@IWS  Percentages alone do not allow a test for exactly the reason mentioned. 0 head and 1 tail are a completely different situation from 0 heads and 1 million tails, etc. A chi-square test must be based on frequencies. This is true across all software or indeed true if you are doing the calculation directly.

Comment: With some percentages, their values will allow you to put a high enough lower bound on the numbers involved that you could have something potentially worth testing (e.g. 23.53% vs 73.33% cannot involve lower n's than 17 and 11 respectively), but your percentages admit n's as small as 5 and 2, which is not going to be worth thinking about

Comment: See discussion here:[Chi Square Analysis Percentages](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104323/chi-square-analysis-percentages)

Comment: Code to calculate the lowest sample size (total frequency) consistent with a given set of percentages and extent of rounding in reporting is given in  Becker, R. A., J. M. Chambers, and A. R. Wilks. 1988.  _The New S Language: A Programming Environment for Data Analysis and Graphics._  Pacific Grove, CA: Wadsworth and Brooks/Cole p.272ff. An example is that 60% and 40% are compatible with 5 = 3 + 2 (but also 10 = 6 + 4, 15 = 9 + 6, etc.).